# What is the difference between (Superclass/Subclass) Total and Partial Specialization?

Tags: database-design, erd, database-diagrams, subtypes

What is the difference between *total* and *partial specialization* of superclass/subclass (or supertype-subtype) structures in *enhanced entity-relationship* modeling?